# need help on jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my html code i have something like this.

```
<ul id="selections">
                        <li id="tt">
                            <div style="background-color: #0099ff; width: 200px;">
                                <a style="padding: 5px;" id="aa" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'new_user'; ?>">New User</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div style="background-color: #0099ff; width: 200px;">
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'old_user'; ?>">Existing User</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div style="background-color: #0099ff; width: 200px;">
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'management_hod'; ?>">Managements / HOD</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div style="background-color: #0099ff; width: 200px;">
                                <a href="<?php echo base_url() . 'hr'; ?>">HR</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
</ul>
```

then I'am using jquery to animate this,

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#tt").mouseover(function() {
                    $("#aa").stop().animate({
                        padding: "5px 5px 5px 100px",
                    });
                });

                $("#tt").mouseout(function() {
                    $("#aa").stop().animate({
                        padding: "5px"
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
```

this script now works for first

item without any problem. but the thing is I'don't have any idea how to apply this effect to other li items.

any help?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a class like `.tt` for all of those `li` and try the following,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $(".tt").mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
                        padding: "5px 5px 5px 100px",
                    });
                });

                $(".tt").mouseout(function() {
                    $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
                        padding: "5px"
                    });
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$("ul#selections li")
```

instead of

```
$("#tt")
```

example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $("ul#selections li").mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
                        padding: "5px 5px 5px 100px",
                    });
                });

                $("ul#selections li").mouseout(function() {
                    $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
                        padding: "5px"
                    });
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for selecting all the 4 elements. eg.

```
$("ul#selections > li")
```

instead of

```
$(".tt")
```

So it becomes:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("ul#selections > li").mouseover(function() {
                $("#aa").stop().animate({
                    padding: "5px 5px 5px 100px",
                });
            });

            $("ul#selections > li").mouseout(function() {
                $("#aa").stop().animate({
                    padding: "5px"
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the work for you:

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5CaCs/)

```
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#selections li").mouseover(function() {
                    $('a', this).stop().animate({
                        padding: "5px 5px 5px 100px",
                    });
                }).mouseout(function() {
                    $('a', this).stop().animate({
                        padding: "5px"
                    });
                });

            });
```

So you can make your selector the id of the `ul` and target the li inside it and in the animate method your need to change your selector to `$(this)` because it will tell your code to run in the context of the current selector.

*You can chain your methods like this to boost up the performance.*